How to only update a specific object in json using jq
I read a json from a file, manipulated one of the fields such as below and got the output on terminal
cat list.json | jq ".module.home.[].names | map(.long=\"$long\")"

However, the original file i.e. list.json is still having old values. How do I update only this object back in the original file.
Solutions such as here replaces the whole content with the output of command. However, what I want to is only update a particular object such as ".module.home.[].names in it, and leave the rest as it is.

Try using the |= update operator: .module.home.[].names |= map(…)

Do it like so:
jq --arg long "$long" '.module.home[].names[] += {$long}' list.json > list.json.new
mv list.json.new list.json


Can be shortened to .module.home[].names[] += {$long}

@pmf Yeah, next time post an answer not a comment
